# Not able to access objects in a group

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have some objects which are added to a group(sphereMesh). I'm trying to detect clicks on the objects. But unable to detect it. SO here is my code

```js
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
    vector = vector.unproject(camera);

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(sphereMesh.children, true);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {

        console.log(intersects[0]);

        intersects[0].object.material.transparent = true;
        intersects[0].object.material.opacity = 0.1;
        intersects[0].object.material.color= 0x000000;

    }
}
```

I want to change the colour of the object. But unable to do it.

Comment: Is `sphereMesh` in your code an array of objects?

Comment: Yes. I'm adding a sphere to each vertices of Icosahedron. These spheres I've added to the group(sphereMesh).

Comment: vector.z should be 1 instead of 0.5